# "FOR UPDATE...SELECT * FROM DELETED" Trigger copying to table with two extra columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a very simple trigger that copies the current row of

- `Authors`: `AuthorID(PK)`,`AuthorName`,`Bio`
- `AuthorsHistory`: `HistoryID(PK)`, `AuthorID`, `AuthorName`, `Bio`, `hWhen(dateTime)`

`hWhen` uses `getDate()` to fill in its value.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[AuthorHistory]
ON [dbo].[B_Authors]
FOR UPDATE
AS
    INSERT INTO B_AuthorsHistory 
        SELECT * 
        FROM deleted
```

There are more columns but they don't matter for this point. All columns are the same types, same null settings, same default values, other than the PK changing.

It works perfectly, but today I wanted to add a column.

- I tried to add it to `Authors` which immediately threw an error, something about column list in the trigger. (I'm using `Select *`)
- I added the column first to `AuthorsHistory`, tried `Authors` again, and it threw a different error directly mentioning the trigger.

I found a resolution, remove the trigger, adjust columns, add the trigger, but I also had to remove `hWhen` from `AuthorsHistory` temporarily (this isn't an issue at the moment, still building it).

Another option, probably, is to be specific with column names and values. **I do this in code**, but I like the idea of one less thing to update if I can avoid it.

**The question**: is there a way I can do this with SELECT *?** I have an identical trigger (ie "`Products ==> ProductsHistory`") on other tables as well.

Comment: Dont use the SSMS designer to add your columns, if you just use TSQL you should be able to add them to both tables in turn fine. e.g. http://rextester.com/NNIWQN4856

Comment: Okay, thank you. @MartinSmith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, the only way to add a new column to both tables, so that trigger wouldn't fail, is to do it in one query like that:

```
;disable trigger dbo.AuthorHistory on dbo.B_Authors;

alter table dbo.B_Authors add NewColumn int null;

alter table dbo.B_AuthorsHistory add NewColumn int null;

;enable trigger dbo.AuthorHistory on dbo.B_Authors;
```

But if you have high loaded system, you may lose some data in `dbo.AuthorsHistory` if any other transaction would change data in `dbo.Authors` in the middle of the query.

Comment: My interpretation is that they are seeing this when adding the column not by concurrent executions. which would be explained by SSMS recreating the table (with new columm) and then trigger (now out of synch) after the change is made. Hopefully they wont be using SSMS table designer to make changes to production.

Comment: I agree. Anyway it's always better not to use `select *`.

Comment: Audit triggers are a case where personally I'm happy for `SELECT *`. it means that if you add a new column to the base table it is virtually impossible to forget to add it to the history table (as you will get runtime errors due to the mismatch)

Comment: Martin is right, and thanks GriGrim. As a rule, it's 'always' better but there are occasions where it's useful. In this case, I need to know everything about the row that was modified. I'm not delivering this row to to anyone. **Thanks again to both of you**